# Pass data though @selector to textField

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:textField action:@selector(setText:)];
```

How do I send a piece of info with the setText action. For instance

```
setText:@"This is text"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured as an action `setText:` will be called with an `(id)sender` where `sender` will be your `UIButton`. If you were using a custom UIButton you could give it a property to hold the text you wanted to pass and then access that within your action method. Since you're using `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` you cannot.

Let me guess what you want to do: let the user enter some text and pass that back to a parent view controller when they click done.

If so, try this:

1. Give your view controller a property (and IBOutlet) for the text field.
2. Access that in `setText:`

So...

```
- (void)setText:(id)sender
{
    NSString *theText = self.textField.text;

    // now do what you wanted...
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: What is there was not only one text field? Is there a way to send the textField object across?

Comment: @CoreCode, I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean — that sounds like a different, or more complicated question. Perhaps you could edit yours to clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self performSelector: @selector(setText:) withObject:@"This is text" afterDelay:0.0];
```